# List formatting in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list that looks like this (but a lot larger):

```
list = [0.010128, 0.007897, 0.999918, 8890, 1.97, 424, POLARIS;, UMI, ALPHA], ['0.462045', '0.181562', '0.868072', '8538', '2.66', '403', 'RUCHBAH;', 'CAS', 'DELTA']
```

I want to format the list to change/combine the last 3 items:

```
list = [0.010128, 0.007897, 0.999918, 8890, 1.97, 424, 'POLARIS', 'UMI ALPHA'], ['0.462045', '0.181562', '0.868072', '8538', '2.66', '403','RUCHBAH', 'CAS 'DELTA']
```

but I just can't seem to get it done.

Comment: And did you try anything? Because I don't see any code, and if you don't try then how you can get it done?

Comment: format your code first.

Comment: Yes I tried a lot of things, none of which worked.

Comment: What kind of things did you try and what is the output?

Comment: I tried to format your code, and found that it isn't even valid code.   Post something valid.

Comment: We would like to see the code which didn't work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can combine last 3 items in **list** using following code:

```
list = [0.010128, 0.007897, 0.999918, 8890, 1.97, 424,'POLARIS', 'UMI', 'ALPHA']
x1=list[0:6]
data=list[6:9]
print data
x=" ".join(data)
print x
x1.append(x)
print x1
```

output:

```
     [0.010128, 0.007897, 0.999918, 8890, 1.97, 424, 'POLARIS UMI ALPHA']
```

If you want to combine last two items then use

```
  x1=list[0:7]
  data=list[7:9]
```